# keep getting this error for nodemediaclient react native IOS each time i attempt to build app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, react-native

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "___darwin_check_fd_set_overflow", referenced from:    _kmp_read in NodeMediaClient(kmp.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation

Comment: Seems You try to build for iOS simulator but the linked library doesn't contain arch for it. Do you have the same problem when build for your device?

Comment: first i tried on a simulator and i got this error and then i removed node_modules,pods , installed them and built directly to my device and i still got the same error

Answer (score 1):

fixed it today, turns out that i was using xcode version 11.3.1, and i needed to update my xcode version to version 11.5 and above and i also noticed 11.5 wont be compatible with my mac Os version so i did also update to the latest version of catalina and react-native-node-media-client works fine :)